# Using Import syntax in React native Image

Tags: react-native, react-native-image

Can I use import syntax instead of require as suggested by [react native docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image#docsNav)

I assume both are same. If not why? Will that improve the performance of loading images?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the latest React Native tutorials use the new import syntax.
The main difference is, **import** is **ECMAScript 6(ES6)** syntax and require is **ECMAScript 5(ES5)**.

Answer (score 1):

yes you can use import. `require` is old syntax and import is new one introduced in ES6.